# Delete words that start with '#', except for the first n such words

Tags: ruby, regex

Given a string and an integer n, I want to remove all words starting with "#" after the nth occurrence.

For example, if n = 2 and the string is:

"The mountains of **#Chamonix** France are famous for skiing, alpine climbing, base-jumping, **#Paragliding**, raw adventure and **#Home** of the first Winter Olympics. It's an adventurers and photographers paradise. Seen here, a long exposure of the **#Druis**, one of many striking"

Then the result should be:

"The mountains of **#Chamonix** France are famous for skiing, alpine climbing, base-jumping, **#Paragliding**, raw adventure and of the first Winter Olympics. It's an adventurers and photographers paradise. Seen here, a long exposure of the, one of many striking"

The first two #-prefixed words, `#Chamonix` and `#Paragliding`, were preserved, but the remaining #-prefixed words, `#Home` and `#Druis`, were removed.

Comment: The question is unclear, please reformulate. Right now, it looks as if you want to take the number `2` from the string, and remove 2 `#...`s from the end.

Comment: Which words are the same words?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to remove all words starting with `"#"` after the nth occurrence, then:

```
string.gsub(/#\w+/).with_index(1){|s, i| i > n ? "" : s}
```

Comment: One does not often see `gsub` returning an enumerator. Good example of its utility.

Answer (score 0):

This should work (easy, readable way):

```
saved = 0
str.split.map do |word|
  ret = word
  if word[0] == '#'
    if saved == n
      ret = ''
    else
      saved += 1
    end
  end
  ret
end.join
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with [String#gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) and a regular expression as follows.

```
str = "The #quick, brown #dog #jumped over #the #lazy fox"
n = 2 # Number of words beginning with '#' to skip

r = /
    (?:     # start a non-capture group
    \#\w+   # match a word beginning with '#'
    [^#]+   # match all characters other than '#'
    )       # end the non-capture group
    {#{n}}? # do that n times, lazily
    \K      # disregard everything matched so far
    \#\w+   # match a word beginning with '#'
    /x      # extended mode

str.gsub(r,'')
  #=> "The #quick, brown #dog  over   fox"
```

Answer (score -1):

If I get your question right, you want to remove all hash-tag words after `n`. You can do it like this:

```
str = "The mountains of #Chamonix France are famous for skiing, alpine climbing, base-jumping, #Paragliding, raw adventure and #Home of the first Winter Olympics. It's an adventurers and photographers paradise. Seen here, a long exposure of the #Druis, one of many striking"
n = 2

str.gsub(/#{str.scan(/#\w+/)[n..-1].join('|')}/,'')
# => "The mountains of #Chamonix France are famous for skiing, alpine climbing, base-jumping, #Paragliding, raw adventure and  of the first Winter Olympics. It's an adventurers and photographers paradise. Seen here, a long exposure of the , one of many striking"
```

**Explanation:**

First we get all hash-tag words:

```
str.scan(/#\w+/)
# => ["#Chamonix", "#Paragliding", "#Home", "#Druis"]
```

Now we care about only words after 2nd index, i.e.

```
str.scan(/#\w+/)[n..-1]  # n is 2
# => ["#Home", "#Druis"]
```

Now lets create a regex pattern to find these words in String. Here:

```
/str.scan(/#\w+/)[n..-1].join('|')/
# /#Home|#Druis/
```

Finally replace them with `''` using `gsub`. Keeping all things together, we get:

```
str.gsub(/#{str.scan(/#\w+/)[n..-1].join('|')}/,'')
```

Comment: Suppose you have `str = "#foo #bar #baz #foo"`. Your answer will remove not only the `"#foo"` at the end but also the `"#foo"` at the beginning.